# Python zipfile large file hangs forevers

Tags: python, python-zipfile

python -m zipfile -c ~/testbig.zip ~/verylarge4gbfile.zip

It hangs forever.

Is there a better python library I can use?

I'm using the command as a POC that the library doesn't seem to work for large files, so I need another python library option, although I suppose I could also use a system command and call it through python, but I'd prefer to handle progress of zipping the file[s].

EDIT: I ran it again, and after 30 minutes it finished. I suppose I just need a way to monitor progress, or chunk the zipping process.

Comment: gzip should work I believe

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: gzip worked wonders!

Comment: FYI I was using 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use GZip. It's iteratable, so you can for loop through the data to watch for progress.